# Convert Object List Into Map

Tags: java

I have list of objects which have two properties {alpha,beta} as below :

```
obj1 = {alpha1,beta1}
obj2 = {alpha2,beta2}
obj3 = {alpha3,beta3}
obj3 = {alpha1,beta2}
obj5 = {alpha3,beta1}
```

I want to create a map such as `Map<alphaKey,List<beta>>`

so It will like below :

```
alpha1 --> beta1,beta2
alpha2 --> beta2
alpha3 --> beta3,beta1
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: I think best way would be to use a mehod which take **obj** in parameter and check if the key exists in the map. If it exists it adds the value in the sub list, otherwise it crates a new key/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ObjectAB {
    Alpha a;
    Beta b;
    // Gettters and constructuor
}

    ObjectAB[] objArray = new ObjectAB[5]; 
// add obj1, obj2 to it.


    Map<Alpha, List<Beta>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    for (ObjectAB objectAB : objArray) {
        Alpha a = objectAB.getA();
        List<Beta> bList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (map1.containsKey(a)) {
            bList = map1.get(a);
        }
        bList.add(objectAB.getB());
        map1.put(a, bList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try  **Multimap** in **google guava** lib

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<alphaKey, List<beta>> map = new HashMap<alphaKey, List<beta>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {
        boolean isContain = map.containsKey(objList.get(i).getAlphaKey());
        if (isContain)
            map.get(objList.get(i).getAlphaKey())
                    .add(objList.get(i).getBeta());
        else {
            List<beta> betaList = new ArrayList<beta>();
            betaList.add(objList.get(i).getBeta());
            map.put(objList.get(i).getAlphaKey(), betaList);
        }

    }
```